# php - write failed: No space left on device (28)

Tags: php, session

I got session error at php on cenots 5.1 x86.

```
Warning: Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/opt/lampp/tmp/session) in Unknown on line 0
```

The owner is `nobbody:nobody` for `/opt/lampp/tmp/session`, and permission is 0777.

Hard disk usages:

```
[root@localhost Documents]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                      50G  47G    0 100% /
tmpfs                504M  956K  503M  1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1            485M  68M  392M  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home 96G  199M  91G  1% /home

[root@localhost Documents]# df -i
Filesystem            Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                    3276800  977907 2298893  30% /
tmpfs                128858      5  128853    1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1            128016      52  127964    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home 6332416    422 6331994    1% /home
```

Any helpful comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your `/` is full and you are attempting to save to `/opt/...` which is on `/` too. You'll have to find what is filling your `/` and free up some disk space.

You can find what's using your disk space with something like this

```
cd /
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec du -sh {} \;
```

which will list the size of each top level directory. You can then drill down using the same find command.

Comment: After executing "find . -maxdepth 1 -exec du -sh {} \;", the prompt blinks so long tome and does not stop.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root 50G  47G    0 100% /`

`... session.save_path is correct (/opt/lampp/tmp/session) ...`

Ack. Your session save path is on `/`, which is full.

Comment: David Schwartz/ Thanks a lot for comment.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @Iain's command, you can use `du -m |awk '$1>5000'` to only list directories occupying more than 5GB, but not limited to the top level. Depending on how deep in the tree the culprit is, this might save you some typing (of `cd xx && du ...`)

Comment: Ansgar Esztermann/ I'll study. Thanks!